# Mac terminal has no response to Python commands (unless there is a syntax issue)

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Take your basic

```
print "hello world"
```

Saved into a .py then ran in terminal (cd /Users/etc to the file location first) does nothing but move to the next empty line. Now if there is something wrong with the syntax the I'll get a message:

```
trsynshMBP:~ trissynashville$ python 
/Users/trissynashville/Documents/Python/sample.py
File "/Users/trissynashville/Documents/Python/sample.py", line 1
print "hello world"
                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

But if the syntax is correct, then I get:

```
trsynshMBP:~ trissynashville$ python 
/Users/trissynashville/Documents/Python/sample.py
trsynshMBP:~ trissynashville$
```

No response. And it's not like I'm just defining a command, right? Print should bring the text up in terminal, no?

Anyway, I'm new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Can you include - the input, the output, what you expect to happen, what actually happens and how they differ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic:

```
print "Hello World"
```

is actually:

```
print("Hello World")
```

in python 3. That is what the `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` is referring to.

Also, to run a python file without a shebang, you must run it with the python command

```
>> python sample.py
Hello World
```

or

```
>> python3 sample.py
...
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: Ok, but I'm using Python, not Python 3. And I did try the python filename above with no response.

Comment: There is no Python. There is a Python 2, and a Python 3. Find out which version you are using by typing `python` in the command line. It will display the version.